# Why it caused SIGSEGV (signal 11) (core dumped)?

Tags: c, arrays, function, runtime-error, structure

Here I have function which gets a string array from struct and returns struct integer_array.

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
integer_array* my_count_on_it(string_array *p1)
{
    integer_array *pusher;
    int size = p1->size;
    char** str = p1->array;
    pusher = (integer_array*) malloc(size*sizeof(integer_array));

    for (int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        pusher->array[i] = strlen(str[i]);
    }
    return pusher;
}
```

Function prototype(c):

```
  typedef struct s_string_array {
    int size;
    char** array;
  } string_array;

 typedef struct s_integer_array {
   int size;
   int* array;
 } integer_array;

@param {string_array*} param_1
@return {integer_array*}


integer_array* my_count_on_it(string_array* param_1) {

}
```

---

This is how should it work

Input/Return Examples:

**Input:** ["This", "is", "the", "way"]
**Return Value:** [4, 2, 3, 3]

**Input:** ["aBc"]
**Return Value:** [3]

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. (that said -- my crystal ball suspects you have uninitialized pointers in `p1->array` such that `strlen(str[i]);` craters...)

Comment: How is `my_count_on_it()` called. What is passed in and how is this defined and initialised/set by the caller?

Comment: The point is, without [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), all we can do is guess. There is nothing inherently wrong (or right) in what you have posted.

Comment: Honestly, seeing `(core dumped)` after your application has crashed is awesome! That means the operating system has created a core file, which you can open with a debugger and see where the crash happened in your source code. This is a great opportunity for you to learn how to analyze such a core file, which will undoubtedly help you in the future.

Comment: The function `my_count_on_it' is actually defined twice and this may result in a covered implementation. You should not use braces for prototypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integer_array *pusher` is initialized well. But the individual pointers in it should also be initialized. You may probably want to do this `pusher->array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) *size)` . But honestly speaking, I did not get a grasp on what you wanted to achieve with that function call. You declared an array of `integer_array` but you seem to use only the  first element, I suspect their is a potential logic error in your code.

Edit: As @David C. Rankin mentioned, it may also be that you did not assigned a valid value for `p1->array`

You may want to have your functions like this.

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct s_string_array {
    int size;
    char** array;
} string_array;

typedef struct s_integer_array {
    int size;
    int* array;
} integer_array;

integer_array* my_count_on_it(string_array *p1)
{

    integer_array* pusher = (integer_array*) malloc(sizeof(integer_array));

    pusher->size = p1->size;
    pusher->array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * p1->size);

    for (int i = 0; i < p1->size; i++)
    {
        pusher->array[i] = strlen(p1->array[i]);
    }
    return pusher;
}

int main()
{
    string_array *p1 = NULL;

    /* collect data from user */

        // Setup p1{} struct

    integer_array* pusher = my_count_on_it(p1);

    for (int i = 0; i < pusher->size ; i++)
        printf(" %d ", pusher->array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```